# Лента уведомлений

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать чтобы при нажатии на уведомление открывалось приложение и содержимое уведомления(Заголовок, Текст сообщения) добавлялось в  главный активити, в список.

Comment: `PendingIntent` + `StringExtra`?

Comment: @Flippy StringExtra можете пояснить, что это?

Comment: ой) ну, изучите передачу данных по интентам

Answer (score 1):

Формируем интент:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("test", "test");
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Используем в NotificationCompat.Builder примерно так:

```
.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT))
```

И в MainActivity получаем Bundle:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String test = intent.getStringExtra("test");
```